# Drupal 7 - Convert Custom Variables to Dimensions - Google Analytics module

Tags: drupal, google-analytics, drupal-7, universal-analytics

I recently updated the Google Analytics Module to 7.x-2.1 
I have created dimensions in my Google Analytics account but struggling with how to add dimensions (for my obsolete custom variables) on the Drupal module UI
The UI only has 2 columns - Index & Value - If I use a token here how will it map to the Dimension I created in GA?

Would really appreciate you help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I have no recent experience with Drupal this seems straightforward - Custom Dimensions in Google Analytics are not addressed by a token, but by their numeric index (basically the order of creation in the interface - you can see the index in the custom  dimensions overview table).

The alphanumeric name (I assume that is what you mean by "token") is used in the reporting interface only, it does not show up in the tracking code.

Comment: Thanks Eike. Appreciate your time. I totally ignored the possiblity that Index is assigned based on the order of creation in GA. Realized it when I actually started created dimensions. Basically creating Dimensions in GA and Drupal in the same order.